# Tag pytorch-dataloder should be corrected

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There is a misspelled tag that needs correcting: [pytorch-dataloder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch-dataloder). It currently has *24* questions while the correctly spelled tag [pytorch-dataloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch-dataloader) has none.

Weirdly enough, I remember having seen [pytorch-dataloder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch-dataloder) get renamed to [pytorch-dataloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch-dataloader) in the past, is it possible that it got changed back?

Comment: you can do it yourself and "empty" tags are removed automatcally

Comment: Probably belters wrote the tag name.

Comment: @nbk, while users can do small retags themselves, it is preferred to just get a moderator to rename the tag as it's a one-click for mods.

Comment: @BhargavRao this is a small retag, mderators have a lot td bso my advice was perfect

Comment: @nbk, one of the tasks of mods is to also handle retag requests. This takes a maximum of 2 minutes to do, so it isn't that hard. That said, if no mod had checked it within 4~5 days, then going ahead with retagging would be totally fine.

Answer (score 5):

> you can do it yourself and "empty" tags are removed automatcally

Done: retagged all *26* questions to [pytorch-dataloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch-dataloader). Glad I have the <kbd>Edit tags</kbd> tool available!

Comment: Ouch, you received a wrong advice there, this would have been one click for moderators. Retagging all the posts causes some disruption, as it bounces the questions on the main page.

Comment: Sorry about that, I would have probably refrained from doing it had there been more mistagged questions.

Comment: It's alright. Just keep this in mind in future.